# loop or function to compare two column values and create new variable in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I have two big and small dataframes (actually dataset is very very big !). The following just for working.

```
big  <- data.frame (SN = 1:5, names = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), var = 51:55)

 SN names var
1  1     A  51
2  2     B  52
3  3     C  53
4  4     D  54
5  5     E  55

small <- data.frame (names = c("A", "C", "E"), type = c("New", "Old", "Old") )
  names type
1     A  New
2     C  Old
3     E  Old
```

Now I need to create and new variable in "big" with the help of "type" variable in small. The names in small and big will match and corresponding type will be stored in column type. If there is no match between the names columns it will be result in new value "unknown". The expected output is as follows:

```
resultdf <- data.frame(SN = 1:5, names = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), var = 51:55, 
              type = c("New","Unknown", "Old", "Unknown", "Old"))

resultdf 
  SN names var    type
1  1     A  51     New
2  2     B  52 Unknown
3  3     C  53     Old
4  4     D  54 Unknown
5  5     E  55     Old
```

I know this is simple question for experts but I could not figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use `merge()` with the argument `all=TRUE` to merge the two data.frames, keeping rows of `big` that found no matching value in the `small$names`. Then, replace those elements of `big$type` that didn't find a match (marked by `merge()` with "NA"s) with the string **"Unknown"**.

Note that because `big` and `small` share just one column name in common, that column is by default used to perform the merge. For more control over which columns are used as the basis of the merge, see the function's **by**, **by.x**, and **by.y** arguments.

```
small <- data.frame (names = c("A", "C", "E"), 
                     type = c("New", "Old", "Old"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
big  <- data.frame (SN = 1:5, names = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), var = 51:55,
                    stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

big <- merge(big, small, all=TRUE)
big$type[is.na(big$type)] <- "Unknown"
```

Comment: @ Josh, I can see that you put "stringsAsFactors=FALSE" as part of data, can you explain the reason ..thanks for quick response

Comment: @John -- To see why, try performing the assignment in the final line without having used `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` when constructing the data.frames. R will complain, because you are trying to assign a **character** string `"Unknown"` into a column that is of class **factor**. Because there is no existing level of that factor called `"Unknown"`, it won't work. (It's worth trying to see, as the error message you'll get is informative).

Answer (score 1):

```
big$type <- c(as.character(small$type),"Unknown") [
                                    match(
                                       x=big$names, 
                                       table=small$names, 
                                       nomatch=length(small$type)+1)]
```

The basic strategy is to convert the factor to character, add an "unknown" value, and then use big$names to look up the correct index for "types" in the 'small' dataframe. Generating indices is a typical use of the match function.